# Angular and rest web service causes: "Expected response to contain an object but got an array"

Tags: angularjs, spring, web-services, rest, resources

I practicing angular and web services. My goal to make angular service which gets data from web service. Connection to server is made and server returns some data. Problem is that I receive error:

```
    Error: $resource:badcfg
Response does not match configured parameter
Error in resource configuration for action `featured`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array (Request: undefined products/featured)
```

I don't know exactly where is my mistake, or $resource is implemented wrong, or Spring controller made in bad way? Maybe someone can give any suggestions, what is the best way to make it work?

my code:

**WebService controller:**

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductManagementController {

    @Autowired
    ProductManagementService productService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/featured")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ProductModel>> getFeaturedProducts() {
        List<ProductModel> products = productService.getFeaturedProducts();
        if (products.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<ProductModel>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<ProductModel>>(products, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/recommended")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ProductModel>> getRecommendedProducts(){
        List<ProductModel> products = productService.getRecommendedProducts();
        if(products.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<List<ProductModel>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<ProductModel>>(products,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**Angular service:**

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';

    var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp');
    mainApp.factory('ProductService', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('products/:action/:sub', {}, {
            'featured' : {
                mothod : "GET",
                params : {
                    action : 'featured',
                    sub : ''
                }
            }
        });
    } ]);

    mainApp.controller('featuredItems', [ '$scope', 'ProductService',
            function($scope, ProductService) {
                ProductService.featured(function(responseData) {
                    debugger; //This breake point is not colled 
                });
            } ]);
})();
```

Comment: Go to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource and look for `isArray`. Also, it's `method`, not `mothod`.

Comment: `isArray` did the trick? I did't catch a little bit in documentation. This parameter is needed always when I receive List from server?

Comment: Apparently, yes. I never use $resource. I prefer using $http directly.

Comment: hmm, is `$http` has any advantages over `$resource`, because as I noticed in some sources explaining angular requests to server, that for rest services is better to use $resource.

Comment: $resource is an abstraction level above $http. Since $resource uses $http, you can do everything $resource does with $http. But I find the code more readable and intuitive with $http. It's a matter of opinion, but that's mine.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to resemble with your `featured` action is the in-built `query` action which definition is `'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true}` according to the documentation. You always have to do this when receiving arrays of objects.